# Can't break promise chain with return

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a chained promise using `.then()`, the issues I am having is i'm getting `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` - I know why i'm getting it (there are 2 responses in the promise) however after doing lots of reading I can't figure out how to break the `.then()` callback - i've been trying to use `return`, however it keeps running to the next chain in the promise.

How do I stop the chain at the first `res` - response, when the `checkResult` if statement is `false`?

**Promise Chain**

```
  await query1()
    .then((checkResult) => {
      if (!checkResult) {
        return res.status(200)
      }
    })
    .then(() => query2())
    .then((result) => {
      return res.status(201).json({ result: result, status: 201 });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(`Error occurred: ${err}`));
```

**Query 1 Example**

```
  async function query1(){
    return false
    }
```

Comment: you're already using `await`, why bother with promise chaining? if you stick to `await` you can stay in the same function instead of going in callback after callback, which means returning would actually stop the function like you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `async/await` which simplifies control flow issues like these:

```js
  try {
    let checkResult = await query1();
    if (!checkResult) {
      return res.status(200);
    }
    let result = await query2();
    return res.status(201).json({ result: result, status: 201 });
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(`Error occurred: ${err}`));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Klaycon - For my learning, is there a solution using promises too?

Comment: @tbowden I'd strongly advocate against using promise chaining like this as a general rule, so my preferred solution is "don't do this". But if someone were to force you at gunpoint, you should know that the value returned from each `.then()` handler is always passed on to the next one (even if nothing is returned, the next one simply gets `undefined`). So the only way is to check in each handler if the previous handler doesn't want to exit the chain. Or you can throw, which kicks it out of the chain to the first `.catch()` handler following.

Comment: Thank you @Klaycon! I’ll be using a async/await!